# Parse XML through httprequest directly in the DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a Httprequest to get a XML file and it works well !

My JS Function :

```
function sendData()
{   
        var xdr = getXDomainRequest();
        xdr.onload = function() 
        {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xdr.responseText;
        }

        xdr.open("GET", "myURL");
        xdr.send();
}
```

I have now something like this appended in "#myDiv" :

```
<div id="myDiv">

<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<liste>
<produits>
<produit>
<nomprod>TEXT</nomprod>
<desc>TEXT</desc>
<texte>TEXT</texte>
</produit>
</produits>
</liste>

</div>
```

Now, I would like to PARSE this XML contained in "#myDiv" and styling it

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call `xrd.send`, you'll have access to the the xml document through `xrd.responseXML`.  You can then use DOM functions to manipulate `xrd.responseXML`, For instance, you could get `<noprod>`'s value like so:

```
var nomprod = xrd.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('nomprod')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Then you could do what ever you want with the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to frameworks, you can use jQuery to simply send an ajax call that will load and parse your XML.

```
$.get("myurl.xml", function(data){
    xmldata = $.parseXML(data);
});
```

you can then iterate over `xmldata` and create and style your own HTML representation.

sources:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Thanks for answer but as I said I don't have an .xml file I append my XML content directly in a div

Comment: no, you use an http request to get the xml file. you can change your entire request code to this, and shorten it to 3 lines of code instead of 10

Comment: if you load it this way, you will have an Object with all of the xml structure inside it, you will be able to create and append HTML element to the page.

Comment: I need httprequest because I send some vars to a distant service which require an httrequest